# Azure Functions not creating Azure Tables Columns Locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage-emulator

I am attempting to create an Azure Function.  Locally I want to be able to test my function before I deploy it. I am developing on a MacOS 11.2.3 using VS Code.  I am using [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) as my local storage emulator running in Docker.  I can connect to the local emulator and see my Queues and Storage.  My Functions app is using netcoreapp3.1 and is a Functions v3 app.

My trigger is a new payload received by a queue.  My trigger works just fine and when I write my data to the Azure storage table, I can see the RowKey, PartitionKey and Timestamp.  I cannot see any of the data I have created.  Here is my code:

```
public static class MyFunction
{
    [FunctionName("MyFunction")]
    [return: Table("mytable")]
    public static MyObject Run([QueueTrigger("myqueue")]string queueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed");
        var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(queueItem);
        log.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject));
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

Here is MyObject.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace MyProject.models
{
    public sealed class MyObject : TableEntity
    {
        public MyObject(string myProperty)
        {
            string PartitionMonth = DateTime.Now.ToMonthName();
            string PartitionYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
            PartitionKey = $"{PartitionMonth}-{PartitionYear}";

            RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            MyProperty = myProperty;

        }
        public string MyProperty { get; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am not seeing the MyProperty Column being made.  My JSON Payload that is given to the queue has it, I can see it logged to the logger, I just don't see the column in Azure Storage Explorer.  I do see a Row made each time I trigger my function.  Please help me understand why I cannot see my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are running into this issue is because you have no public setter for your `MyProperty`.

Please try by changing this line of code:

```
public string MyProperty { get; }
```

to

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

And your code should run just fine.

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/933836a01432da169966017f0848d7d6b05fc624/Lib/Common/Table/TableEntity.cs#L406 (See "Enforce public getter / setter" in the code).

```
internal static bool ShouldSkipProperty(PropertyInfo property, OperationContext operationContext)
{
    // reserved properties
    string propName = property.Name;
    if (propName == TableConstants.PartitionKey ||
        propName == TableConstants.RowKey ||
        propName == TableConstants.Timestamp ||
        propName == TableConstants.Etag)
    {
        return true;
    }

    MethodInfo setter = property.FindSetProp();
    MethodInfo getter = property.FindGetProp();

    // Enforce public getter / setter
    if (setter == null || !setter.IsPublic || getter == null || !getter.IsPublic)
    {
        Logger.LogInformational(operationContext, SR.TraceNonPublicGetSet, property.Name);
        return true;
    }

    // Skip static properties
    if (setter.IsStatic)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // properties with [IgnoreAttribute]
#if WINDOWS_RT || NETCORE 
    if (property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(IgnorePropertyAttribute)) != null)
#else
    if (Attribute.IsDefined(property, typeof(IgnorePropertyAttribute)))
#endif
    {
        Logger.LogInformational(operationContext, SR.TraceIgnoreAttribute, property.Name);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This did work.  I also tried using a private set, and that didn't work either.  Is there a good pattern to use an immutable object AND Azure Tables?